# Measuring peak nvidia GPU memory usage on linux

Tags: linux, bash, cuda, gpu

To measure the GPU memory currently used by my programs I can use the following command (ubuntu linux, nvidia GPU):

```
while true; do nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used --format=csv; sleep .5; done|grep -v memory
```

It will regularly output values like this :

```
70 MiB
74 MiB
75 MiB
76 MiB
77 MiB
77 MiB
70 MiB
```

Is it possible to modify the command to always display the maximum value instead of the latest?

(in a bash-only way, if possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sure, But you can give a try on like this.

```
a=0
while true; do 
b=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used --format=csv|grep -v memory|awk '{print $1}')
[ $b -gt $a ] && a=$b && echo $a 
sleep .5
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Run the following command, and replace <gpu_id> with the gpu in question. You can get the gpu_id by running nvidia-smi

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used --format=csv -i <gpu-id> -l 1
```